# Disable padding added by DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am trying to center my table header text, but because of the bootstrap 3 icons added by the dataTables stylesheet my text is moved slightly to the left. How can I center the text correctly?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover center-all" id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="text-align: center">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" class="headerText">Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

This is the result currently:

[image: Text]

EDIT:

This is where dataTables adds the padding, is there a way to disable this?

[image: Text]

Comment: can you make those icons position:absolute in the stylesheet?

Comment: how do we go about testing what you write? we have to guess?  You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Could be solved by just css. try `position: absolute; right:0` on icon and set th `position: relative`.

Comment: @Kinglish I'm not sure wether that's possible, since the icons are added by dataTables dynamically. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this to my css file, it removes the padding added by DataTables to 0px:

```
table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead > tr > th.sorting, table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting_asc, table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting_desc, table.dataTable thead > tr > td.sorting {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```